# Is there a way to write to kafka topics based on telegraf input?

Tags: apache-kafka, telegraf, telegraf-output-plugins

I want to write the data collected by the agent into different topics in the kafka according to the input plugins. Can we forward the collected data to kafka topics separately according to telegraf inputs?

This is my telegraf.conf file

```
[global_tags]


[agent]
  interval = "20s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 10000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = "0s"
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false


 [[outputs.kafka]]
   brokers = ["127.0.0.1:9092","127.0.0.1:9093"]
   #topic = "telegraf"
   client_id = "abc-def-ghj-klm"
   max_retry = 3

   ## Optional TLS Config
   sasl_username = "test"
   sasl_password = "test123"
   sasl_mechanism = "PLAIN"
   insecure_skip_verify = false
   data_format = "json"


[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = true
  totalcpu = true
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false

[[inputs.system]]

[[inputs.internal]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a simple way, just add "kafka.topic_suffix" conf to your output.kafka settings. After that you could see your new topics that was created automatically by telegraf similiar theese; telegraf_cpu, telegraf_system, telegraf_blabla.

```
 [[outputs.kafka]]
   brokers = ["127.0.0.1:9092","127.0.0.1:9093"]
   topic = "telegraf"
   client_id = "abc-def-ghj-klm"
   max_retry = 3

   ## Optional TLS Config
   sasl_username = "test"
   sasl_password = "test123"
   sasl_mechanism = "PLAIN"
   insecure_skip_verify = false
   data_format = "json"

   [outputs.kafka.topic_suffix]
     method = "measurement"
     separator = "_"
```